# How to create a custom input field helper in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In my Play app, I want to add a custom attribute to my text input field. Therefore, I use this helper:

```
@inputText(userForm("username"), Symbol("my-attr") -> "val: username")
```

I use this helper very often which results in *ugly code duplication*. As a result, I want to encapsulate this in a custom helper.

I tried it like this:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)

@inputType = @{ args.toMap.get('type).map(_.toString).getOrElse("text") }

@input(field, args.filter(_._1 != 'type):_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <input type="@inputType" my-attr="val: @name" id="@id" name="@name" value="@value" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)/>
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can use this by calling, for example: `@inputTextMyAttr`? I am not sure if I get the idea of custom helpers, but the desired result would be to just call:

```
@inputTextMyAttr(userForm("username"))
```

and automatically set `htmlArgs` to `Symbol("my-attr") -> "val: @name"`